# Parse.com: Can I make PFFile calls to files hosted on my own server?

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to configure parse.com to point `PFFile` calls to files on my own server? I would like to organize my files into groups/folders (worlds>levels>images) so that with 1 method call I can download all necessary resources, plus easily change swap files when necessary.

P.S. I'm developing on iOS.

Comment: Nope. How else would parse make money?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot configure where PFFile's are stored. At this point in time I believe Parse stores it's files as blobs on Amazon S3.

It sounds like you have some particular requirements for file storage. Have you considered simply storing references to URLs, rather than PFFiles, in your Parse objects?

Even if a PFFile was pointing to a different server, the Parse SDK still wouldn't allow you download multiple resources with a single method call.